# Send Excel data in outlook body with borders alignment

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

below code working fine to send excel data in outlook body with borders , question is how to alignment the all data which pasted in body to the center.

Thank you

```
Sub esendtable()


Dim outlook As Object
Dim newEmail As Object
Dim xInspect As Object
Dim pageEditor As Object

Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set newEmail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

With newEmail
    .To = Sheet1.Range("A2").Text
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Data"
    .Body = "Please find the requested information" & vbCrLf & "Best Regards"
    .display

    Set xInspect = newEmail.GetInspector
    Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor

    Sheet1.Range("B2:E5").Copy

    pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.End = pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
    .display
    .Send
    Set pageEditor = Nothing
    Set xInspect = Nothing
End With

Set newEmail = Nothing
Set outlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: .body doesn't allow text formatting, you should use HTML (.HtmlBody) and format your text with html tags

Comment: thank you, what I want is when the new email window display the message(table) which pasted from excel to be alignment to the center. I try this but it doesn't work (pageEditor.Application.Selection.alignment=center)

Answer (score 0):

it seems that this will generate the html code for you, and format your table as it is formatted in excel

```
Sub esendtable()


Dim outlook As Object
Dim newEmail As Object
Dim xInspect As Object
Dim pageEditor As Object

Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set newEmail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

With newEmail
    .To = Sheet1.Range("A2").Text
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Data"
    .body = "Please find the requested information" & vbCrLf & "Best Regards"
    .display

    Set xInspect = newEmail.GetInspector
    Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor

    Sheet1.Range("B2:E5").Copy

    pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.body)
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.End = pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
    .display
    Set pageEditor = Nothing
    Set xInspect = Nothing
End With

Set newEmail = Nothing
Set outlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you,  what I want is when the new email window display the message(table) which pasted from excel to be alignment to the center. I try this but it doesn't work  (pageEditor.Application.Selection.alignment=center)